# Matching pairs of gloves

Tags: probability

A closet contains $13$ different pairs of gloves. The 26 gloves are randomly arranged into $13$ pairs.

(a) Find the probability that all left-hand gloves are paired with right-hand gloves (not necessarily matching).

(b) Find the probability that all of the gloves are arranged so that each left-hand glove is paired with its matching right-hand glove.

Updated:

To deal with (a). First I get the number of ways to arrange 26 gloves into pairs ($n=13$), the order does not matter: $$\frac{(2n)!}{2^{n}}\cdot\frac{1}{n!}$$

After that, I calculate the number of ways in which all left-hand gloves are paired with right-hand gloves (not fully matching): $n!=13!$

So the probability of (a) equals: $$n!\cdot\frac{(2^{n})n!}{(2n)!}$$

And the probability of (b) equals (only one case when all gloves are fully matching): $$\frac{(2^{n})n!}{(2n)!}$$

Is my approach correct?

Comment: "the qualified exam in 2018"? At least not globally nderstandable, there might be a thing in your country called that, but it doesn't mean anything to me.

Comment: Neither of your answers is correct. Look at some smaller examples (say 4 gloves). Where are you getting the $n!$ from?

Comment: You're nowhere near the correct answers.

Comment: I suggest you begin by figuring out the size of the sample space.  In how many ways can you form $13$ pairs of gloves from $26$ gloves?

Comment: If you start with $2n$ gloves, you take any glove, and then take another: what is the probability the second is a suitable match for the first in the part you are considering?  If it is, then you have reduced the problem to $2n-2$ gloves so you can continue.

Comment: Let's enumerate left-hand gloves from 1 to 13. Consider first left-hand glove. Probability that her pair is right-hand is 13/25, not 0.5. Probability that her pair is matching right-hand glove is 1/25.

Comment: @Henriksupportsthecommunity you are right, it's not related to the problem. I have edited it.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig So may I approach this problem by calculating the number of ways to arrange 26 gloves to 13 people (26C2)x(24C2)x...x(4C2) and the number of ways to group in pairs?

Comment: That is the number of ordered arrangements of pairs of gloves.  However, that will give you too large a denominator since the order of the pairs does not matter, nor does the order within each pair.  That said, you are on the right track.  You should update your question with your latest attempt, which is better than your initial attempts.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Thank you so much. I have updated my question and also my approach

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solutions are correct.

There is another way to count the number of elements in the sample space.  Suppose we have $n$ pairs of gloves in the closet. Grab any of the $2n$ gloves in the closet.  It does not matter which glove we choose.  There are $2n - 1$ gloves left in the closet.  Pair one of them with the first glove you select.  Set that pair aside.  Take any of the remaining $2n - 2$ gloves out of the closet.  Again, it does which glove we choose.  Pair any of the remaining $2n - 3$ gloves left in the closet with that glove.  Iterate the process.  The number of ways of forming $n$ pairs of gloves is
$$(2n - 1)!! = (2n - 1)(2n - 3)(2n - 5) \cdots (5)(3)(1)$$
where $k!!$ is referred to as the [double factorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_factorial).

We can verify that this expression is equivalent to your expression as follows.  Based partly on work you did in the comments, you found that the number of ways to place the gloves in pairs is
$$\frac{1}{n!2^n}\binom{2n}{2}\binom{2n - 2}{2}\binom{2n - 4}{2} \cdots \binom{6}{2}\binom{4}{2}\binom{2}{2} = \frac{(2n)!}{n!2^n}$$
Observe that
\begin{align*}
\frac{(2n)!}{n!2^n} & = \frac{(2n)(2n - 1)(2n - 2)(2n - 3) \cdots (4)(3)(2)(1)}{n(n - 1)(n - 2)(n - 3) \cdots (3)(2)(1)(2^n)}\\
& = \frac{(2n - 1)(2n - 3)(2n - 5) \cdots (5)(3)(1)(n!)}{n!}\\
& = (2n - 1)(2n - 3)(2n - 5) \cdots 5 \cdot 3 \cdot 1\\
& = (2n - 1)!!
\end{align*}
where we first cancel a $2$ from each even factor to obtain the expression in the second line, then cancel $n!$ to obtain the expression in the third line.

In this particular problem, $n = 13$, so the number of elements in our sample space is
$$25!! = 25 \cdot 23 \cdot 21 \cdot 19 \cdot 17 \cdot 15 \cdot 13 \cdot 11 \cdot 9 \cdot 7 \cdot 5 \cdot 3 \cdot 1$$

> Find the probability that all left-hand gloves are paired with right-hand gloves (not necessarily matching).

If we place the right-hand gloves in a line (in any order), there are $n$ left-hand gloves which can be matched with the first right-hand glove, $n - 1$ left-hand gloves which can be matched with the second right-hand glove, $n - 2$ left-hand gloves which can be matched with the third right-hand glove, and so forth.  Hence, there are $n!$ favorable cases.  Thus, the probability that each left-hand glove is matched with a right-hand glove is
$$\frac{n!}{(2n - 1)!!}$$
In this particular problem, we obtain
$$\frac{13!}{25!!} = \frac{13 \cdot 12 \cdot 11 \cdot 10 \cdot 9 \cdot 8 \cdot 7 \cdot 6 \cdot 5 \cdot 4 \cdot 3 \cdot 2 \cdot 1}{25 \cdot 23 \cdot 21 \cdot 19 \cdot 17 \cdot 15 \cdot 13 \cdot 11 \cdot 9 \cdot 7 \cdot 5 \cdot 3 \cdot 1}$$

> Find the probability that all of the gloves are arranged so that each left-hand glove is paired with its matching right-hand glove.

There is only one favorable case.  Hence, the probability is
$$\frac{1}{(2n - 1)!!}$$
In this particular problem, we obtain
$$\frac{1}{25 \cdot 23 \cdot 21 \cdot 19 \cdot 17 \cdot 15 \cdot 13 \cdot 11 \cdot 9 \cdot 7 \cdot 5 \cdot 3 \cdot 1}$$

Comment: Uhm I think for the (a) part it should be $\frac{(n!)}{(2n-1)!!}$ as you mentioned, right?

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the error.